# Different place of birth on DS2019 and passport

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, j1-visas

Place of birth in DS2019 and Passport is different. City name A is on the DS2019 and village name B is on the passport.

Is it required to have the same place of birth on DS2019 and passport?

Comment: Why did you put a different place of birth in your DS 2019 from the one in your passport?

Comment: @Ankur Kumar Have you asked your designated sponsor? https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/how-to-apply/about-ds-2019/

Comment: @phoog. Actually, at the time of filling passport form, they ask to put the place of birth, so I put my village name. And at the time of filling DS2019 form, they asked "City of birth",so I put the city name. But now it's mismatching.

Comment: @AnkurKumar it seems that you are saying that you were born in the village, but the village is territorially a part of the city -- is that correct?

Comment: @phoog Right.. I born in village and is a part of a city.

Comment: @AnkurKumar then both of your documents are factually correct.  I wouldn't worry too much about it, as suggested in Giacomo Catenazzi's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/132461/19400).

Comment: @Ankur kumar What did you add, city name or village name in the application

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is a problem. In a lot of documents (and different countries) we have such cases. The real place of birth doesn't change, but documents often list the official name (as at the time of release of the new documents), so places change.

I assume that either the small village is no longer an official political entity (or just no longer an entity for people registering).

If the village is in the same zone of the city: there should be no problem. (exception on contended [maybe just on the past] territories, especially near boundaries).

BTW: I'm in a western country where there is not the concept of "place of birth" (so it is not listed in any document, official or not). Never had problem with visa and immigration on other countries.

Comment: @AnkurKumar I would just point out that the fact that there is no concept of "place of birth"  in Giacomo Catenazzi's country does not depend on the fact that it is a western country.  There are plenty of western countries that *do* have this concept and do list the place of birth in the passport.